# Start Menu and Explorer problems

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

My local user profile on Windows 10 Pro version 1607.14393.321 has been having the following problems since at least 2016/10/17 when update "Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB3199209)" was installed:

1. Start Menu won't open. This was permanently resolved by running file "startmenu.diagcab" which repaired a corrupted tile database and one other thing.
2. Search won't work. This was temporarily resolved by toggling from the Cortana icon to the search box but that no longer works and this hasn't been resolved by anything else (checking Windows services, repairing App components, SFC, DISM, etc).
3. Configuration of Explorer (window size, folder ordering) and System Tray (icon ordering) but not Taskbar is lost on restart of explorer.exe or the PC. Running file "Reset_Notification_Area_Icons_Cache.bat" as my user or as administrator doesn't resolve the problem and reports the following:

> The Explorer process must be killed to reset the Notification Area
>   Icons Cache.
>
> Please SAVE ALL OPEN WORK before continuing
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
>
> SUCCESS: The process "explorer.exe" with PID 10876 has been
>   terminated.
>
> ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or
>   value. Registry key "IconStreams" already deleted.
>
> ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or
>   value. Registry key "PastIconsStream" already deleted.
>
> Windows must be restarted to finish resetting the Notification Area
>   Icons.
>
> Restart now? (Y/N) and press Enter:

Comment: Sounds like you should either roll back to 1511 or use the Reset feature.

Comment: @Ramhound The fresh install was the Anniversary Edition. I don't want to reset as I'd have to reinstall, reactivate, and reconfigure all of my apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, using the `Location` tab to relocate the folder `%localAppData%` causes this so I just recreated my local user profile which resolved all problems.